# Python process critical logging messages

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I am using **Python 2.7.5** with the **logging** module to log messages and display them to the user. I am creating a logger, set the appropriate logging levels and add a formatter to the logger.

Is it possible to add a function which processes messages sent to a specific logging level?
I want to process messages sent to the logging level *CRITICAL*, so I can save and return them later.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple handlers to your logger. For each handler, you can define a separate log level.

So for example, you can have a StreamHandler with log level INFO to log to the console and a FileHandler with log level CRITICAL to log to a file for later inspection.

This is explained in the [section "Multiple handlers and formatters" in the Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#multiple-handlers-and-formatters).